# I am trying to run is visible command

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check the element is visible or not. I have two forms. form 1 have industryQuestions.search-input and #legalBusinessName. form 2 doesn't have both. when I run condition 1 it reloads both forms. But when I run condition 2 it only reloads form 1. while form 1 has both elements. and form 2 doesn't have that element.
I want that only form 2 reload whose doesn't have both elements.

```
//condition 1
if (document.getElementById("industryQuestions.search-input") || $('#legalBusinessName').is(':visible') == false) {
        console.log("industry Type issue");
        location.reload();
    }

//condition 2
if (document.getElementById("industryQuestions.search-input") || $('#legalBusinessName') == false) {
        console.log("industry Type issue");
        location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using both native DOM methods _and_ jQuery? You should probably stick with one or the other.

Comment: when I use one element it continuously reloads both forms OR Doesn't Reload any form

Comment: `industryQuestions.search-input` is not a good `id` attribute value IMO